# Adding a pre-existing index page (root) as a new page on Wordpress so you can link to "Home" in navigation bar

Tags: php, wordpress, indexing, navigation, wordpress-theming

This might be a really stupid question but I am using word presses function to add a navigation bar:
`$menuItems = array('theme_location' => 'primary');`
`wp_nav_menu($menuItems);` so I can add pages and order within the dashboard.

I already have an index page (index.php) in the root of my themes folder. I can't work out how to add it as a page so it will appear in the navigation bar? The URL path to it on the site is just `localhost/wordpress/` but when adding a new page you can't leave the permalink as blank.

Any tips? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a solution if anyone else is having problems with this.

I copied the function from [Building a simple list](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_nav_menu_items) and appended my own link to it at the end like so

```
$homeUrl =  home_url();
$menuList .= '<li><a class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page" href="'. $homeUrl .'">Home</a></li>';
```

The full code is:

```
// Get the location of the navigation menu
$locations = get_nav_menu_locations();

// Get the menu itself from the location (primary is header in my case)
$menu = wp_get_nav_menu_object($locations['primary'] );

// Get the menu items
$menuItems = wp_get_nav_menu_items($menu->term_id);

// Initialise a string to hold the unorded list
$menuList = '<ul id="menu-' . $menuName . '">';

// Iterate through each menu item from the list of all menu items and append
// Name of menu item and url to its page
foreach ( (array) $menuItems as $key => $menuItem ) {
     $title = $menuItem->title;
     $url = $menuItem->url;
     $menuList .= '<li><a href="' . $url . '">' . $title . '</a></li>';
}
// Get the link to home url (in my case root (localhost/wordpress/)
$homeUrl =  home_url();

// Append own link
$menuList .= '<li><a href="'. $homeUrl .'">Home</a></li>';

// Close the unordered list tag
$menuList .= '</ul>';

// Echo the list back to html
echo $menuList;
```

This piece of code is included in the header file where the navigation bar should be, wrapped in a PHP block.

The problem in my case is that using `wp_nav_menu($menuItems);` would mean that the hardcoded list item I needed to add wasn't included in the unordered list that the function automatically created, thus causing styling problems.
This unpacks the list, appends own custom link, and displays it.